# How do append employeeID to a file path?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have this path:

http://localhost/myfolder/uploads/filename.pdf

This is the code that creates that link:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("filenameName") %>'
 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("filePath") %>'>
 </asp:HyperLink>
```

The uploads folder is in web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="FilePath" value="~/uploads/"/>
</appSettings>
```

We would like to append an ID to the filePath so that the link looks more like this:

```
http://localhost/myfolder/uploads/**12338**filename.pdf
```

I have tried a few things that have not worked so far.

For instance, I have tried inserting a record by concatenating the ID with filePath:

```
Insert into my table(filePath) Values(@ID+' '+@apFileName)
```

This inserts successfully. However, the link now displays as:

http://localhost/myfolder/12338/filename.pdf which is what is inserted into the database with the above INSERT statement.

I tried concatenating the query:

```
select ID+" "+filePath as filePath but same result as above.
```

The reason we are appending the ID is to prevent users from uploading a file with same filename which will overwrite a file of same name.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Any insight as to where the extra "/" is coming from at the end of the @ID parameter?

Comment: @NoAlias, thanks for your response. If I am not mistaken, you are suggesting that if I remove the extra "/" from uploads in web.config like like below:

  <add key="FilePath" value="~/uploads" />, it will be fixed?

No, it won't. If remove that, the resuls is :http://localhost/myfolder/uploads12338

Comment: No, I'm asking if you know where the extra "/" comes from after the ID, but before the filename.

Comment: @NoAlias, when you  say `extra`, what do you mean?

I am taking the extra to mean // = one extra "/"

Comment: http://localhost/myfolder/12338/filename.pdf - The extra "/" that I refer to is the one between 12338 and filename.pdf.

Comment: @NoAlias, Oh I see, sorry.

Yes, what is happening is that when save the path using the INSERT statement I showed above, the uploads folder, for some reason, is replaced with the ID.

So instead of localhost/myfolder/uploads/12338filename.pdf, the ID replaces the folder and becomes the folder name, completely different reason from what I intended it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are binding the values in UI. may be adding that id from the Code behind to the variable "filenameName" might help?

Comment: I did that in filenameName which works for filename but not the path which is really confusing because the file path is just the uploads you see in web.configure file.

So, when I tried select ID+" "+filenameName as filenameName, it appends that to filename but not in filepath.

Comment: I am sorry I am confused..    is this the expected path ? http://localhost/myfolder/uploads//**12338**filename.pdf

Comment: yes but without the astericks.

localhost/myfolder/uploads/ is the path on web.config. Then once a filename is selected, it saves the filename, the path to the database and uploads the filename to the uploads folder which gives the path you referenced.

What I don't understand is that in the database, the filename 12338filename.pdf. That file name is appended to the path. So, why isn't the filename on the path reflect the 12338filename.pdf?

It just reflects the filename without the ID appended.

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet of saving the file in the Upload path? So if my understanding is correct in DB the filepath is stored correctly but in the physical path the file name is not prefixed with the ID.